# Is it good practice to ALWAYS cast variables in C?

Tags: c, winapi, coding-style, casting

I'm writing some C code and use the Windows API. I was wondering if it was in any way good practice to cast the types that are obviously the same, but have a different name? For example, when passing a `TCHAR *` to `strcmp()`, which expects a `const char *`. Should I do, assuming I want to write strict and in every way correct C, `strcmp((const char *)my_tchar_string, "foo")`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't. But also don't use `strcmp()` but rather `_tcscmp()` (or even the safe alternatives).

`_tcs*` denotes a whole set of C runtime (string) functions that will behave correctly depending on how `TCHAR` gets translated by the preprocessor.

Concerning safe alternatives, look up functions with a trailing `_s` and otherwise named as the classic string functions from the C runtime. There is another set of functions that returns `HRESULT`, but it is not as compatible with the C runtime.

Answer (score 4):

No, casting that away is not safe because `TCHAR` is not always equal to `char`.  Instead of casting, you should pick a function that works with a `TCHAR`.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e0z9k731(v=vs.71).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Casting is generally a bad idea. Casting when you don't need to is terrible practice.

Think what happens if you change the type of the variable you are casting? Suppose that at some future date you change `my_tchar_string` to be `wchar_t*` rather than `char*`. Your code will still compile but will behave incorrectly.

One of your primary goals when writing C code is to minimise the number of casts in your code.

Answer (score 0):

My advice would be to just avoid `TCHAR` (and associated functions) completely. Their real intent was to allow a single code base to compile natively for either 16-bit or 32-bit versions of Windows -- but the 16-bit versions of Windows are long gone, and with them the real reason to write code like this.

If you want/need to support wide characters, do it. If you're fine with only narrow/multibyte characters, do that. At least IME, trying to sit on the fence and do some of both generally means you end up not doing either one well. It also means roughly doubling the amount of testing necessary without even coming close to doubling the functionality you provide to the user.